# Calling a method in another class to convert an object to that class

Tags: java, android

I was wondering about something very basic but that I haven't been able to figure out. I've read the similar questions, but they don't particularly answer my question.

Let's say I have a string. I want to convert it into a double. Now I see that there is a function known as parseDouble in java.lang.Double. However, how do I call it? The string is in my Android strings.xml file if that's any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the String from your xml file in an Activity, use

```
String s = this.getString(R.string.mystring);
```

You convert it to a double in the way OscarRyz said, although if you don't want a Double object you can do

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

You can also do it all in one step:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(this.getString(R.string.mystring));
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm still not used to the object oriented aspect of Java. Didn't think to just first call up the Double class when I needed the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s  = "0.0";
double d  = Double.parseDouble( s );
```

When you see the doc, and there is a class method ( those marked with the `static` keyword )  means that you have to use the name of the class and then the method name ( like in `Double.parseDouble`)

The other methods, the instance methods, should be invoked on a instance of the class. An instance of the class is an objects created from that class.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was confused between instant and static methods.

Comment: That's *instance* and *class* methods :)

Comment: Wow, I went 0 for 2 on free throw attempts huh?

Answer (score 0):

The method is a static method, and you call it as such

Double.parseDouble("3.14159");

Static methods are methods that do not need to be called on an instance of the class, and doing so will cause a compiler warning(as well as put you in greater risk of the much dreaded NullPointerException)

For instance, the following is equivalent but will result in a compiler warning:

Double bob=new Double(3.14);
bob.parseDouble("3.14159");

You do not actually need to create a Double object to use the static method parseDouble.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I went ahead and reviewed static and instant methods, and now I feel very dumb.